# Getting the error as ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because: Unsupported config option for services: 'db' while composing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydbsecretpassword
  wordpress: 
    image: wordpress
    ports: 
      - "8085:80"
```

While composing the file I am getting the error:
`ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'db'`

Docker version is **18.09.5**

Docker compose version is **1.17.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the compose `version:` at the top -

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="mydbsecretpassword"
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8085:80"
```

Version compatibility - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Comment: Thanks its working. But when i put version: '1.0' it doesn't work. May I know why?

Comment: Version 1 does not support services. Omit the services definition if you are using version 1 of compose file.

Comment: Ideally, you should use the latest one. Also, it depends on your engine version as well, have added compatibility matrix doc.